# rails user-ip from within the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm wondering if there's a more direct way to get and record a users IP in the model itself.  I've been doing it from the controller but I noticed using the rakismet gem it mentions doing everything from within the model, but not the IP specifically.

http://github.com/joshfrench/rakismet

Currently I'm doing this, just before I save from the controller.  It works fine.

```
@notification = Notification.new(params[:notification].merge(:user_ip => request.remote_ip, :user_agent => request.user_agent, :referrer => request.referrer))
```

Comment: Interesting question. My understanding is that it's not the model's job to know where the request is coming from; that's the controller's job. Perhaps someone else knows differently

Answer (score 0):

I think this little trick might be what you're looking for:
http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models

Strictly speaking it's a violation of the MVC pattern, so it should be used carefully.